# .NET 8 build issue: The analyzer assembly references version '4.8.0.0' of the compiler, which is newer than the currently running version '4.7.0.0'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-8.0

I upgraded my SDK to .NET 8, but there is an issue when I build my project which is using .NET 6!

The error:

> Error CS9057  The analyzer assembly 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\source-generators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.dll' references version '4.8.0.0' of the compiler, which is newer than the currently running version '4.7.0.0'.

I already read this question: [How to fix "The analyzer assembly references version '4.7.0.0' of the compiler, which is newer than the currently running version '4.6.0.0'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76740942/how-to-fix-the-analyzer-assembly-references-version-4-7-0-0-of-the-compiler)

But they mentioned removing .NET 8 to solve the problem!

My SDK list:

```bash
7.0.404 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

.csproj:

```cs
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
</PropertyGroup>
```

At this moment I can't upgrade this project to using .NET 8 (on the plan).

Is there any way to solve the issue without removing .NET 8 SDK?

Comment: Have you tried options from the first answer - using `global.json` to select SDK and upgrading nugets to corresponding latest version (i.e. 6.x.x). Also try installing .NET 6 SDK.

Comment: Also can you please post a [mre] somewhere?

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks, Yes it solved my issue by using ``global.json``, I posted an answer though, and mentioned your answer as well.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 6):

**Upgrade to VS 17.8.3 solved the issue without using `global.json`**

**Previous Solution:**

Many thanks to @GuruStron it solved my problem with his answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76741003/6023173

I try to reproduce it here in my case, my SDK list is like this:

```
PS > dotnet --list-sdks
7.0.404 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

So I had to add `global.json` in the root of project (near `*.sln` file) by running this command:

```
PS path-to-sln-file> dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 7.0.404
```

which version `7.0.404` is my last SDK version to build the project. So that command will add `global.json` like this:

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "7.0.404"
  }
}
```

Now everything is fine for me.