# Cannot compile with latest Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I updated my Visual Studio 2022 - Pro to Version 17.8.7 today and now my project will not compile with the analyzers on. We are multi-targeted for `netcoreapp3.1` and `net6.0` as we are moving toward 6. The project has been compiling fine until the VS upgrade.

The error we are getting is `The analyzer assembly 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\codestyle\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeStyle.dll' references version '4.9.0.0' of the compiler, which is newer than the currently running version '4.8.0.0'.`.  The Analyzers under Dependencies are pointing to `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\..\codestyle\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeStyle.dll`

```
<AnalysisLevel>6</AnalysisLevel>
<AnalysisMode>All</AnalysisMode>
<NuGetAudit>false</NuGetAudit>
```

The level was `latest`

```
> dotnet --version
8.0.201
> dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.419 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

To fix this currently, we have to uninstall .NET8 and Visual Studio then install a prior version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET 8 build issue: The analyzer assembly references version '4.8.0.0' of the compiler, which is newer than the currently running version '4.7.0.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77513481/net-8-build-issue-the-analyzer-assembly-references-version-4-8-0-0-of-the-co)

Comment: The global.json file worked when placed beside the sln file. It was beside the csproj files. Thanks.